# Am I allowed to use H.264/MP4 video files in a commercial game?

Tags: copyright, licensing, online

I use Adobe Media Encoder to convert my files to h.264/mp4 files. Am I allowed to use these converted files in a commercial project?

webm is another option, but in comparison to mp4 files, they are harder to work with. mp4 works perfectly.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the Law Stack Exchange. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://law.stackexchange.com/help), especially the section named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).
You are asking about the legal terms related to h.264 files. That is probably fine to ask about, but you should include where to find them, and which part worries you and why.
If you want us to read the complete terms to answer your question, then your question is likely off-topic here.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite possible that whoever plays the video needs a license to do so. If you buy a Windows PC, a Mac, an Android phone or an iPhone, the manufacturer or the provider of the OS has paid for that license. But you need to check that.

For example, MacOS doesn't come with a license that allows end users and applications to convert music to .mp3 format (apparently Apple has a license for iTunes, but not for the whole of MacOS).